# Consistent, complete axiom system that proves its own consistency

Tags: logic, proof-theory, incompleteness

Is there a consistent, complete axiom system that proves its own consistency?

I know that this question isn't exact and I haven't defined when an axiom system proves its own consistency because that's just human interpretation.

Comment: The question was asked by Hilbert and answered in the negative by Gödel http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gödel%27s_incompleteness_theorems

Comment: That wouldn't be a contradiction to a positive answer of my question. I read Gödel's original paper.

Comment: @Jonathan: It would be a contradiction if the theory is also recursively enumerable.

Comment: No, that's wrong.

Comment: The theory can be recursively enumerable. But it has to be weak enough.

Comment: Gödel's prove only works for systems that are strong enough. Roughly speaking, a system is strong enough iff every primitive recursive relation is representable in the system.

Comment: You're right, it needs to also interpret arithmetic. But how do you plan on formulating "$T$ is consistent" without interpreting arithmetic?

Comment: Yes, you're right, I was sloppy when I commented. The closest attempt I've seen to what you ask for is Presburger Arithmetic (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presburger_arithmetic) but still, it doesn't seem to do what you ask for.

Comment: Our system is allowed to interpret arithmetic, but it is not allowed to interpret too much arithmetic. For example: Presburger arithmetic can speak about addition but is complete.

Comment: Can you write me the sentence in Presburger arithmetic whose content is "Presburger arithmetic is consistent"? Or what it even means for "a theory to prove a contradiction" as a formula?

Comment: It should be noted that for weak theories contain some of arithemetic, e.g. Robinson arithmetic, Q, the usual way to express consistency of a theory (e.g. by Godel numbering and predicate Con_T() ) does not work. For example, Con_Q (Q) does not really express the consistency of Q itself, unlike the more natural case of PA (where Com_PA (PA) has a good sense of expressing the consistency of PA). Causz' Con_Q does not satisfy the derivability conditions. However, Con_PA (Q) could be seen to express the consistency of Q (in PA).

Answer (score 5):

Dan Willard published several papers about this topic in the *Journal of Symbolic Logic*. One place to start is the short Wikipedia article "[Self-verifying theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-verifying_theories)".  I am not familiar with the detailed proofs about Willard's theories, but when I have heard him talk about them he indicated they do not prove that multiplication is a total function, and in that way manage to remain weak enough to avoid the incompleteness theorem.

Comment: Thanks. In the Wikipedia article it is written that there are consistent theories proving their own consistency. Are there also such theories which are complete and prove their own completeness?

Comment: Do you know whether there are such theories?